# Extracting data from html pages using R

Tags: html, xml, r, web-scraping, readlines

I tried extracting data from the following site:

```
https://www.zomato.com/ncr/restaurants/north-indian
```

using **R** programming, I'm a learner and beginner in this field!

I tried these:

```
> library(XML)

> doc<-htmlParse("the url mentioned above")

> Warning message:
> XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://www.zomato.com/ncr/restaurants/north-indian'
```

This was one...I also tried the `readLines()` to which the output was as follows:-

```
> readLines("the URL as mentioned above") [i can't specify more than two links so typing this]

> Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

> In addition: Warning message:

> In file(con, "r") : unsupported URL scheme
```

I understand that the page is not XML as shown in error stated, but what is other way around for me to capture the data from this site...I did try tidy html to convert it to XML or XHTML and then work it up but I reached nowhere, maybe I don't know the actual process of using tidy html yet! :( not sure!
Suggest something to solve this issue and corrections if any are there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rvest` package is also pretty handy (and built on top of the `XML` package, amongst other packages):

```
library(rvest)

pg <- html("https://www.zomato.com/ncr/restaurants/north-indian")

# extract all the restaurant names
pg %>% html_nodes("a.result-title") %>% html_text()

##  [1] "Bukhara - ITC Maurya "                "Karim's "                            
##  [3] "Gulati "                              "Dhaba By Claridges "                 
## ...
## [27] "Dum-Pukht - ITC Maurya "              "Maal Gaadi "                         
## [29] "Sahib Sindh Sultan "                  "My Bar & Restaurant "                

# extract the ratings
pg %>% html_nodes("div.rating-div") %>% html_text() %>% gsub("[[:space:]]", "", .)

##  [1] "4.3" "4.1" "4.2" "3.9" "3.8" "4.1" "4.1" "3.4" "4.1" "4.3" "4.2" "4.2" "3.9" "3.8" "3.8" "3.4" "4.0" "3.7" "4.1"
## [20] "4.0" "3.8" "3.8" "3.9" "3.8" "4.0" "4.0" "4.7" "3.8" "3.8" "3.4"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `getURL` from the `RCurl` package to get the document content.  Then we can parse that with `htmlParse`.  Sometimes `htmlParse` has trouble with certain content. In that case it's recommended to use `getURL`.

```
url <- "https://www.zomato.com/ncr/restaurants/north-indian"

library(RCurl)
library(XML)

content <- getURL(url)
doc <- htmlParse(content)

summary(doc)
# $nameCounts
# 
#      div        a       li     span    input  article       h3     meta 
#     1337      362      232      212       33       30       30       27 
#      img   script       ul     link  section        p       br     form 
#       26       21       20       17        7        6        3        3 
#     body   footer       h1     head   header     html noscript       ol 
#        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1 
#   strong textarea    title 
#        1        1        1 
# 
# $numNodes
# [1] 2377
```

Also, note that `readLines` does not support `https`, so that error message is a little less shocking.

Comment: thank you! that helped! i have a query though, what is str(doc) command doing here? stating class of doc?

Comment: @ParulChauhan `str` is a compact version of the object's structure, kind of like a summary.  But the `str` for this doc really didn't show anything except the classes.

Comment: okay i didn't see you used summary() instead of str() in recent edit..quick save! thanx again